# I'm scraping instagram with selenium and nokogiri, and I want to refine my code

Tags: ruby, selenium, nokogiri, screen-scraping

First, English is not my first language, sorry if anything is written in a weird way.
A teacher challenged me to download the pics of my instagram profile, so I decided to use ruby, selenium and nokogiri. After a lot of mishaps I made it, but not in a good way I think. Right now I'm selecting every **img** element and then finding the links inside using ruby.

```
arr = doc.search('img').map(&:values)

images = []
arr.each do |ele|
  ele.each do |link|
    if link.include?("cover")
      images << ele[-2]
    end
  end
end
```

I can't seem to find a good way to find the links using just nokogiri.
The links are in a **srcset** but I can't reach it using a generic way with nokogiri, I assume it's possible to search for it, but I don't know how.
I know it's not recommended but I included a pic of the data, because the formatting it's ugly.
[Nokogiri pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cDbzR.png)

Besides this I have a question about scrolling, because right know I'm only hardcoding a few scrolls like this:

```
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)")
sleep 1
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)")
sleep 1
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)")
sleep 2
```

I thought that maybe I can monitor the length of the `arr = doc.search('img').map(&:values)` but If I add more scrolls the length begin to shrink, I have no idea why, yet.

So as you can see my code kind of sucks. I want to have a better understanding of nokogiri and selenium web driver, if anyone can recommend a good resource for learning about these topics (or maybe I just need to read the docs a third time?), I'd really appreciate it.

Finally here is the link to the complete code https://pastebin.com/fscHf6Ah, because maybe someone can give me pointers in general.
Thanks in advance, for taking the time to read and help.

Comment: SO is generally intended for a [specific question -> specific answer format](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Your question may be more suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

I suggest focusing on the basics, because they're more important and broadly applicable than any specifics about Nokogiri and Selenium:

**Variable Naming**

`links` is an example of a decent variable name. However, `s`, `ele2`, `clean` give very little indication of what they are and what purpose they serve. My guess at what they are (I may be mistaken) and what more appropriate names may be are: `attrs_with_slash_p`, `attr`, and `img_rel_urls`

I encourage you to even use dictionaries and thesauruses to help find better names & words. I do it all the time even though English is my first language!

**Variable Naming 2**

Oftentimes, if you can't come up with a good name for something, the code can be reorganized so you're creating different "things" that can be better identified with a good name. Case in point: "`attrs_with_slash_p`" is both an awkward name and and awkward "thing" (abstraction) to have created.

Here's an example alternative:

```rb
link_attrs = links.flat_map { |ele| ele.to_a }
# "link_attrs" is a more natural name and "thing"

img_rel_urls = link_attrs.flat_map do |attr|
  attr.scan(/\/p\/.+/) # .include?('/p') not needed, this produces a strict subset
end
```

**Leveling up in Ruby /w `Enumerable`**

You'll see from my example above, I used `flat_map`/`map` instead of `each` and `<<`.

Ruby's [`Enumerable`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Enumerable.html) has a fantastically powerful & useful API compared to many other languages. Play around with them and understand what they do. Leveraging its semi-functional interface to the fullest will improve your code a lot.

Comment: Thank you so much, for taking the time to review my code, still I have trouble with the search in Nokogiri, but I really appreciate your suggestions, I’m gonna add the changes right away.